# Degree of a self-complementary graph with $4k+1$ vertices

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

How can we prove that every self-complementary graph on $4k+1$ vertices has a vertex of degree $2k$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number of vertices of degree $d$ is equal to the number of vertices of degree $4k-d$. Thus for all $d\ne2k$ the number of vertices with degree $d$ or $4k-d$ is even. Since there is an odd number of vertices, there must be at least one remaining vertex with $d=2k$.

Comment: Could you explain why does the degree of vertices need to come in pairs of sum 4k ?

Comment: @akshay: You're probably referring to the original version of the answer; I'd slightly reworded it in the meantime and removed the reference to pairs. Anyway, for $d\ne2k$ we have $4k-d\ne d$. Denoting the number of vertices with degree $d$ by $n(d)$, we thus have $n(4k-d)=n(d)$, with $4k-d\ne d$, for a total of $n(d)+n(4k-d)=2n(d)$ vertices, an even number. The only vertices not included in these even counts are the ones with $d=2k$, so there must be at least one of them to make the total number of vertices come out odd.

Comment: Thanks Sir for your help :)